# pd.to_datetime producing inconsistent results for columns in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-3.7

I'm using pandas 1.0.3 with Python 3.7.7.

`filelist.txt` contains a list of filenames, sample below:

```
['2017_12_31_06_05_22_0568015522_2.40E_54.03N_VV_C11_GFS025CDF_wind_level2.nc\n']
['2017_12_30_06_14_22_0567929662_0.27E_53.81N_VV_C11_GFS025CDF_wind_level2.nc\n']
['2017_12_29_06_21_46_0567843706_1.64W_54.27N_VV_C11_GFS025CDF_wind_level2.nc\n'] 
['2017_12_28_17_42_04_0567798124_0.95E_54.10N_VV_C11_GFS025CDF_wind_level2.nc\n']
```

I use the code below to extract the date and time from this list to try and find the closest datetime in `df_lidar`, sample below:

```
datetime_copy       x       datetime
2017-12-30 00:00:00 290.0   2017-12-30 00:00:00
2017-12-31 00:10:00 290.0   2017-12-31 00:10:00
2017-12-31 00:20:00 290.0   2017-12-31 00:20:00
2017-12-31 00:30:00 290.0   2017-12-31 00:30:00
2017-12-31 00:40:00 290.0   2017-12-31 00:40:00
2017-12-31 00:50:00 290.0   2017-12-31 00:50:00
2017-12-31 01:00:00 290.0   2017-12-31 01:00:00
```

Both datetimes are added to `df_events` so I can then compare the difference between the dates using `df_events['time_diff']=df_events['closest_lidar']-df_events['SAR_time']`.

This fails with 
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`.

`df_events['time_diff']=df_events['closest_lidar'].astype(datetime.timedelta)-df_events['SAR_time'].astype(datetime.timedelta)` gives the following error `TypeError: dtype '<class 'datetime.timedelta'>' not understood`.

I would like your help **to get these into the same format** so I can calculate the time difference to the nearest time in `df_lidar`

Looking at the `df_events` :

```
    SAR_time             closest_lidar
0   SAR_time             closest_lidar
1   2017-12-30 06:14:22  "2017-12-10 13:50:00   2017-12-10 13:50:00
                         Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]"
2   2017-12-29 06:21:46  "2017-12-10 13:50:00   2017-12-10 13:50:00
                         Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]"
```

The datetimes are formatted differently, despite using `pd.to_datetime()` for both columns.

`print( type(df_x['datetime']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

`print (type(SAR_time))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`

Full script below:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#from windrose import WindroseAxes
import re
import datetime

user_name = os.getenv("USERNAME")
path = 'C:\\Users\\' + user_name + '\\' + 'data\\'
df_lidar = pd.read_pickle(path +'\lidar.pkl')

#filelist from satellite winds website
f = open(path + 'filelist.txt', 'r')

filelist = [line.split(',') for line in f.readlines()]
df_events= pd.DataFrame(index = range(len(filelist)))

#create empty columns to populate in loop
df_events['SAR_time']= np.nan
df_events['closest_lidar'] = np.nan

#go through each filename in filelist - extract date and find closest date in df_lidar
for i, j in enumerate(filelist):
    event_raw = filelist[i]
    event = str(event_raw).strip('['']')
    event_time = re.findall(r'\d\d\d\d_\d\d_\d\d\_\d\d_\d\d\_\d\d', event)
    event_string = str(event_time).strip('['']')
    event_string= re.sub(r"[^0-9]", "", event_string)
    event_string= re.sub(r"\s+", "", event_string)
    event_timestamp = pd.to_datetime(event_string, infer_datetime_format=True)
    idx = df_lidar.iloc[df_lidar.index.get_loc((event_timestamp), method ='nearest')]
    df_x = idx.to_frame()
    df_x = df_x.transpose()

    df_x['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_x['datetime'])
    SAR_time = pd.to_datetime(event_timestamp)

    #single date here but double date in df_events below
    df_events.iloc[i] = {'SAR_time':event_timestamp, 'closest_lidar':df_x['datetime']}

df_events['time_diff']=df_events['closest_lidar']-df_events['SAR_time']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the columns to datetime format by:

Eg.:

```
    a                   b
0   2017-12-30 00:00:00 2017-12-30 00:00:00
1   2017-12-31 00:10:00 2017-12-30 00:00:00
```

Convert to datetime format:

```
df["a"] = pd.to_datetime(df["a"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df["b"] = pd.to_datetime(df["b"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Then you can find diff:

```
df["diff"] = df["a"]-df["b"]
```

Output:

```
    a                   b           diff
0   2017-12-30 00:00:00 2017-12-30  0 days 00:00:00
1   2017-12-31 00:10:00 2017-12-30  1 days 00:10:00
```

Hope this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Usually that is what I would use. but this does not work, I do not get an error message when using `pd.to_datetime()` but I still get the `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'.`

Comment: Did you try keeping the `'SAR_time'` and `'closest_lidar'` as string itself inside the loop and after the loop ends, finally convert them to `pd.datetime` outside and find the difference?